# Problem to start the TipCalc.Forms mvvmcross app with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, mvvmcross

I am new in the Xamarin.Forms world and the mobile development and I am trying to understand how the framework mvvmcross works. To do it I have taken the example app TipCalc. I am getting a problem when I start this app on a virtual emulator with Visual Studio 2017. I am getting the following error: "TipCalc.Forms has stopped".

Emulator configuration:

Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo (Android 8.1 - API 27) 1GB

I have following components installed:

Android SDK Platform 27 and Google Play/APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image are installed.
Android SDK Tools 26.1.1 and Android Emulator are also installed. NDK is not installed. I am getting an error without any detail when I try to install it.

My development environment:
Windows 10 Home
Processor: Intel Core i7-7500U - RAM 8 GB 64Bit-OS

Any idea why it doesn't work? Build and deploy works fine (deployment takes a long).

Comment: add more details of what fails and what doesn't work if you try to debug an android app

Comment: For example I am trying to start the example of mvvmcross TipCalc and the application starts but I can see nothing. 
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/TipCalc
And generally the deploy process is very slow. Emulator has 512 MB RAM. Should I give more RAM?

Comment: I was getting right now following error: XF002 - Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets. Is it normal getting so many errors only to run a XamarinForms HelloWorld App?